# How can I retrieve dynamic CRM custom field values using java-script?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

How can I retrieve dynamic CRM custom field values using java-script and perform some calculation with the values retrieved and put it to another custom field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this [article](http://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/crm-2011-javascript-xrm-page-basics/) to know more about the structure to access to objects through Javascript.
To get values is like Konrad said, to put a value you need do that:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("CRMFieldName").setValue('Some Value');
```

To do operations is apply Javascript, check this site to learn [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

You can refer to them as to any other field on any form.

```javascript
// assuming the name of your field is *Konrad*
var coder = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“new_Konrad”).getValue();
```

However, if you wish to access the same data field from the context of an IFRAME populated by a web resource, you need to refer to the parent of your location by prefixing the line above by the following.

```javascript
// assuming the name of your field is *Konrad*
var coder = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(“new_Konrad”).getValue();
```

I can add that it's all documented in the SDK but I also need to admit that I'm not visiting it all too frequently myself either.